# Getting a decimal to print with an array

Tags: java, arrays, decimal

I'm trying to get this "for" statement to print out a decimal value for an array, but I can't figure it out.

```
for ( int b = 2; b < totals.length; b++ )
{
    int percent = totals[ b ] / ( 360000 );
    System.out.printf( "%3d%12d%17d\n", b, totals[ b ], percent );   
}
```

I tried doing %.2f on the printf statement, but it wouldn't work.

There's of course more to the code, but I'm not sure if you need to see more to help me out. Any tips would be great.

Edit: Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Roll36K
{

public void rollDice()
{
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    int die1; // number on first die
    int die2; // number on second die
    int totals[] = new int[ 13 ]; // frequencies of the sums


    for ( int index = 0; index < totals.length; index++ )
    totals[ index ] = 0;


    for ( int roll = 1; roll <= 36000000; roll++ ) 
    {
    die1 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt( 6 );
    die2 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt( 6 );
    totals[ die1 + die2 ]++;
 } 


System.out.printf( "%3s%12s%17s\n", "Sum", "Frequency", "Sim. Probability" );


for ( int b = 2; b < totals.length; b++ )
{
int percent = totals[ b ] / ( 360000 );

System.out.printf( "%3d%12d%17d\n", b, totals[ b ], percent );
 } // end for
} // end method rollDice
} // end class Roll36
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What does it print? I suspect, it prints `0` for `percent`?

Comment: What are the content of totals?

Comment: It prints non decimal integers. I would like more exact decimal representations. Rather than just a 2, I would like it to say 2.475 or something. I'll edit my original comment with the whole code so you can get a better idea on what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `percent` variable is an `int`. Integers are by definition whole numbers.

Try this instead:

```
double percent = totals[ b ] / ( 360000.0 );
```

I changed the type of `percent` to `double`, which can be a floating point number (i.e. a decimal).
I also changed `360000` to `360000.0` because `totals[b]` is an `int`. In Java arithmetic on integers returns another integer. Unfortunately that means that the remainder of division is lost. You have to force one of the operands to be a floating point type (such as `double`) to make the division do what you think it does. So you can either manually cast or make the constant a double by adding the `.0`.

Comment: Do I need to make a change to the line: System.out.printf( "%3d%12d%17d\n", b, totals[ b ], percent ); as well?

Comment: @user2585969 Yes. This lets you use `%.2f` like you originally intended.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting should be in the pattern

**%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion**

In your case you are missing out the precision part. try "%3.4d...." for example..

If you can provide your input and expected output, I could help better